# Get Comment in XML file by RapidXML

Tags: comments, rapidxml

I try to get value of a command in xml file. I found the function `type()` on its manual. But it just return numberic value about type of node. Are there any ways to get it?

This is my snippet:

```
 xml_node<> *Node = Doc.first_node();
 xml_node<> *Sub = Node->first_node("Task");
std::cout << "Comment: " << Sub->type() << std::endl;
```

And the value return is: **Comment: 1**

This is file's content:

```
<!-- \GoogleUpdateTaskMachineCore -->    ***<<== this is the value I wanna get.***
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>

<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">

  <RegistrationInfo>

    <Version>1.3.33.7</Version>

    <Description>Keeps your Google software up to date. If this task is disabled or stopped, your Google software will not be kept up to date, meaning security vulnerabilities that may arise cannot be fixed and features may not work. This task uninstalls itself when there is no Google software using it.</Description>

  </RegistrationInfo>

  <Triggers>

    <LogonTrigger>

      <Enabled>true</Enabled>

    </LogonTrigger>

    <CalendarTrigger>

      <StartBoundary>2017-11-14T12:07:01</StartBoundary>

      <ScheduleByDay>

        <DaysInterval>1</DaysInterval>

      </ScheduleByDay>

    </CalendarTrigger>

  </Triggers>

  <Principals>

    <Principal id="Author">

      <UserId>S-1-5-18</UserId>

      <RunLevel>HighestAvailable</RunLevel>

    </Principal>

  </Principals>

  <Settings>

    <MultipleInstancesPolicy>IgnoreNew</MultipleInstancesPolicy>

    <DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>false</DisallowStartIfOnBatteries>

    <StartWhenAvailable>true</StartWhenAvailable>

    <RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>false</RunOnlyIfNetworkAvailable>

    <Enabled>true</Enabled>

    <RunOnlyIfIdle>false</RunOnlyIfIdle>

    <WakeToRun>false</WakeToRun>

    <ExecutionTimeLimit>PT72H</ExecutionTimeLimit>

  </Settings>

  <Actions Context="Author">

    <Exec>

      <Command>C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Update\GoogleUpdate.exe</Command>

      <Arguments>/c</Arguments>

    </Exec>

  </Actions>

</Task>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you'll need need to use the `parse_comment_nodes` flag when you `parse()` the document.

Then, iterate through the nodes until you find a node with `type() == node_comment`, then get the `value()` of that node.

Comment: Great! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @PoseidonSecurity if it worked mark it as the answer and thank them with an up vote...